# How to send confirmation order to an email provided through a post request

Tags: sendgrid, strapi

I have an ecommerce website (no user authentication) which stores some products (localStorage) and creates a post request with the user's mail provided in the form, along with the list of products.
The api path is **www.api.*site*.com/api/orders**. I am wondering how to send the order summary to the user's email, provided in the post request it sent.

Here is my Cart.js

```js
var products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("products"));

  const onSubmit = (data) => {      //on send order button press


    var object = {
      list: products, //the products list
      ...data,      //email and phone
    };

    axios
      .post(`https://api.*site*.com/api/orders`, {
        data: {
          email: object.email,
          phone: object.phone,
          items: object.list,
        },
      }).then(...)
```

I have seen that in every documentation, the controllers send the same mail to the same address
example :

```js
// path: ./src/api/{api name}/controllers/{api name}.js or ./src/api/{api name}/services/{api name}.js 

  await strapi.plugins['email'].services.email.send({
    to: 'valid email address',
    from: 'your verified email address', //e.g. single sender verification in SendGrid
    ...
  }),
```

How can I pass the user's email to the 'from' field? Any suggestion would be much appreciated.